# Expired Account on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: login, users

my admin account on my computer expired. I set the expiry date myself exploring different account modifications but apparently forgot to reset it.

I would like to reactivate it or create a new user account and move my data over. For that

```
usermod -e yyyy-mm-dd username
```

or `sudo adduser user2 admin`

should work but from where would I run it?

So far I tried:

- **TTY** - 
  Problem: It prompts me to log in what I can't as the account is inactive.
- **single user mode** -
  Problem: When I try the commands mentioned above I get errors like 
  "cant lock /etc/shadow  try again later"

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you mount `/` with write permissions in single user mode?

Comment: True, thanks for the hint. Got everything working now.

Comment: Could post what you did as an answer to help future users?